# 3rd order nested classes in typescript

Tags: typescript, inner-classes

> Edit 1, just made it a little shorter, same code as before tho

Just wanted to say that it might look like a lot of code but it's all pretty empty.

---

So I wanted to create a nested class structure that would look like this:

```js
let a = new A();
let b = new A.B();
let c = new A.B.C();
// etc
```

The problem is that typescript kept fighting with me through the different ways to create nested classes. The one method that looked very promising and elegant and which I'm gonna call the `prototype` or the `type` method of doing nested classes.

The problem with the `type` method, is that it doesn't scale up to 3rd order nested classes, meaning, class `C` inside class `B` inside class `A`.

```js
class A {
    // error TS7022: 'B' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.
    public static B = class {
        public static C = class { public constructor(name : string) { } }
        // error TS2502: 'c' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.
        public c : A.B.C;
        public constructor(c : A.B.C) { this.c = c; }
    }

    public b : A.B; public constructor(b : A.B) { this.b = b; }
}

namespace A {
    export type B = InstanceType<typeof A.B>;
    // error TS2456: Type alias 'C' circularly references itself.
    export namespace B { export type C = InstanceType<typeof A.B.C>; }
}

export { A };
```

So that's not working, and I spent the last 8 hours trying to figure out why it's not working, and I still have no clue why. Then I found another method (it's uglier but when expanded it gives no troubles) which I'm gonna call the `namespace` method which goes like this:

```js
class A { public b : A.B; public constructor(b : A.B) { this.b = b; } }

namespace A {
    export class B { public c : A.B.C; public constructor(c : A.B.C) { this.c = c; } }
    export namespace B { export class C { public constructor() { } } }
}

export { A };
```

---

Onto my actual question, I can totally work with the `namespace` method, why the heck is it that the `type` method gives me those errors? They look pretty weird and I have no clue of why ANYTHING would be a circular reference in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would smth like this work?

```
class C {}
class B {
    static C = C
}
class A {
    static B = B
}
```

Comment: I mean, it works if you add the type pattern, where you add the nested classes to the prototype. But that's not really what I'm asking, I'm asking why is the first example not working? I'm getting 3 errors that to me seem to come out of nowhere.

Comment: Does't it say "circular reference" which is quite a clear indication of what's going on?
When you define you class B, you define its elements as being of type A.B / A.B.C.
However, in the namespace, type A.B is derived from the actual class itself (`typeof A.B`).

Your second example doesn't have any back-references via `typeof` in a namespace, so it compiles well

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, so you're saying that what's causing problems is that I define `B` as both a type and a namespace? (thx for answering btw :3)

Comment: Nope. The minimal reproduction of your problem without any namespaces: `type A = typeof B.A; class B { static A: A }`

Comment: Or, to the absolute minimum: `type A = typeof a; const a: A;`